# TAPI no incoming "signals"? How to check the TAPI Driver?

Tags: c#, vb.net, modem, tapi, incoming-call

I try to learn and understand TAPI and I have tried A LOT of examples, all of them get my TAPI Line and I can dial out, but no event is fired when I have an incoming call, so I'm starting to think that the TAPI driver is not working properly/blocked by firewall/something completely different.

Last code I tried is https://pastebin.com/T3ZHkLi0 and I'm getting to `MsgBox("We are here")` end then it exits. Before that it fires the only TAPI line I have.

Is there any way to check why no incoming events are fired?

**Specs**

- Auerswald TAPI Driver: [Specs](https://web.archive.org/web/20190217105436/https://www.auerswald.de/de/service/125-developer-service/1059-dev-function-lan-tapi.html)
- MAYBE I have an estos TAPI driver running, how could I check that?
- ProCall on the Client Computer (interferes possibly?)
- Win10 64 bit

Any hint is highly appreciated

Comment: You have tagged C# and VB6 but provided code in VB.Net, which ones is it? Please take more care when asking questions. Also please don't paste links to code, embed the code in here instead as the pastebin link will likely die very soon.

Comment: the pastebin is set to "unlimited" and I thought it would be counter-productive to have a wall of code that most likely is not the cause of my problems.

Comment: From the [FAQ](http://pastebin.com/faq#18): *At this moment in time we do not delete pastes that do not have an expiration date. But in the future we might automatically delete pastes that have not been viewed by anyone in more than 6 months.*

Comment: And you're right that a wall of code isn't good, but that just indicates that your question doesn't have a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to not use TAPI COM solution and use Julmar .Net 32-bit and 64-bit compatible solution https://github.com/markjulmar/atapi.net. It's wrapper for TAPI.dll and easy to implement.
You can simply convert this c# code into VB

```
TapiManager tapiManager = new TapiManager("TapiCallMonitor.net");
if (tapiManager.Initialize() == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Tapi devices found.");
            this.Close();
            return;
        }
foreach (TapiLine line in tapiManager.Lines)
        {
            try 
            {
                line.NewCall += OnNewCall;
                line.CallStateChanged += OnCallStateChanged;
                line.CallInfoChanged += OnCallInfoChanged;
                line.Monitor();
            }
            catch (TapiException ex)
            {
                LogError(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

You can find full solution [here](https://github.com/markjulmar/atapi.net/blob/master/src/test/TcMon/TapiMonitorForm.cs)